# Ограничение оперативной памяти контейнера в docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, развертывание, виртуальная-машина, deploy

Есть ли возможность ограничить оперативную память для отдельных контейнеров или для целого docker-compose (стэка?)?

Проблема в том что один из контейнеров постепенно съедает около 12гб памяти, а должен ну где то 0.5гб. Понятно что где-то там идет утечка, но сейчас нет времени в этом разбираться. До этого проблема не была заметна, так как на локальном компьютере на docker в целом стоит лимит в ~2гб.

Пытался выставить в yml (`version: "3.9"`), ожидая того же, что и от лимита на докер на локалке:

```
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 1000M
```

Но это не принесло никакого эффекта - сервер ложится от нехватки памяти при попытке задеплоить.

На самом сервере стоит Portainer, деплой идет через него.

Указывайте, пожалуйста, как работает лимит в вашем решении - кладет контейнер/стек на котором он стоит (тоже неплохо - хотя бы весь сервер не будет ложится), либо потребление памяти будет упираться в этот лимит, но класться не будет (я это в лучшем случае ищу).

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось решить проблему, поменяв версию `docker-compose.yml` и изменением самой строки с лимитом:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  ...
  my_service:
    ...
    mem_limit: 0.5GB
    ...
  ...
```

При этом после изменения версии, остальные параметры менять не пришлось. Все работает также как и прежде.

Если теперь ввести `docker stats`, то видно что вместе с цифрой потребления ОЗУ рядом появилась `limit`. Тот который и указан в `docker-compose.yml` у соответствующего контейнера.